# Two function are equal for any probability measure

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

Assume $f,g$ are measurable function on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}).$ Denote by $\mathscr{P}(\mathcal{F})$ the set of all of probability measure on $\mathcal{F}.$

> If for every $\nu\in\mathscr{P}(\mathcal{F})$, we have $\int fd\nu = \int gd\nu$, then $f(\omega)=g(\omega)$ for every $\omega\in\Omega$.

Comment: I guess the problem is hard since we can not know how to describe the measure in $\mathcal{F}$

Comment: In English 'any' can mean 'every' and 'some', which are crucial to distinguish in mathematics. It is better not not to use 'any'.

Comment: Consider the measure $\nu$ that assigns total mass 1 at $\omega.$ The rest is easy.

Comment: @conditionalMethod  Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 1):

Suppose not then $f-g:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is a nonzero measurable function. In particular there is a $c\in\mathbb R$ such that $(f-g=c)\neq\varnothing$. Being measurable means $(f-g)^{-1}(c)\subset\Omega$ is measurable.

If $\nu$ is a positive measure support in $(f-g)^{-1}(c)$, then we are done by contradiction.

The problem is, for non-atomic $\sigma$-algebra, can we can always find a nonzero measure on it? If yes then we can also be done. If no then there will be counterexample for you question.